# How to get refresh output in Servlets using eclipse kepler and Tomcat

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, servlets

I am working on servlets in eclipse kepler and using tomcat server. I have made some changes in servlet and when I run I get the same previous output before making changes. I have cleaned the server, restarted it many time , but It made no difference! What should I do? I am new to servlets

Comment: Is my answer solved your problem?

Comment: This didn't work :( I switched to Jboss!